# Reverse direction of push and pop segue animations?

Tags: ios, swift, uinavigationcontroller, segue

I have a button on the left side of my root view controller the triggers a push segue to another view controller. I would like for the push segue to be animated sliding from the left side to the right side; I would also like the pop animation (for this view controller) to be from the right to left.

I was able to create a custom segue for the push to make the desired animation using this code:

```
import UIKit

class LeftToRightSegue: UIStoryboardSegue {

    override func perform() {
        let src: UIViewController = self.sourceViewController 
        let dst: UIViewController = self.destinationViewController

        let finalFrame  = src.view.bounds
        let initalFrame = CGRect(x: -finalFrame.width, y: 0, width: finalFrame.width, height: finalFrame.height)

        dst.view.frame = initalFrame
        UIView.animateWithDuration(0.25, animations: { dst.view.frame = finalFrame })
        src.navigationController!.pushViewController(dst, animated: false)
    }
}
```

I then tried to create a segue for the pop with the following code:

```
import UIKit

class RightToLeftSegue: UIStoryboardSegue {

    override func perform() {
        let src: UIViewController = self.sourceViewController
        let dst: UIViewController = self.destinationViewController

        let finalFrame  = src.view.bounds
        let initalFrame = CGRect(x: 2*finalFrame.width, y: 0, width: finalFrame.width, height: finalFrame.height)

        dst.view.frame = initalFrame
        UIView.animateWithDuration(0.25, animations: { dst.view.frame = finalFrame })
        dst.navigationController!.popViewControllerAnimated(false)
    }
}
```

but I'm getting the error:

```
fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value
```

at the line:

```
dst.navigationController!.popViewControllerAnimated(false)
```

because the navigation controller is (for some reason) nil.

All I want is for the animations of the push and pop to be reversed, it doesn't matter whether or not it's with custom segues. Does anyone know how I could either fix this implementation, or create a better one?

Update: I've found a VERY hacky solution for the pop:

```
let main = self.navigationController!.viewControllers.first!
self.navigationController!.viewControllers.removeAtIndex(0)
self.navigationController!.pushViewController(main, animated: true)
self.navigationController!.viewControllers.removeAtIndex(0)
```

I'm definitely open to better solutions.

Answer (score 0):

```
    let transition = CATransition()
    transition.duration = 0.3
    transition.timingFunction = CAMediaTimingFunction(name: CAMediaTimingFunctionName.easeInEaseOut)
    transition.type = .push // kCATransitionFromLeft
    transition.subtype = .fromLeft
    navigationController?.view.layer.add(transition, forKey: nil)
    let vc = YOUR_VIEW_CONTROLLER()
    vc.hidesBottomBarWhenPushed = true
    self.navigationController?.pushViewController(vc, animated: true)
```